# Results from query with multiple variables

Tags: java, sparql

I want to add the query results from each variable into a different list. How can I do this?

I use this to get the results when there is only one variable:

```
 List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
                                    while ( results.hasNext() ) {
                                        values.add( results.next().get( "A" ));
                                    }
```

---

My sparql query:

```
 String queryString =
                                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +        
                                "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                                "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
                                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                                "PREFIX onto: <#> " +

                                 " SELECT ?A ?B  " +
                                 " WHERE { ?B onto:property1 onto:aaa . ?A onto:has_input ?B} " ;

                                 Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
                                 QueryExecution qe= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
                                ResultSet resultset = qe.execSelect();
                                ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(resultset);
```

Comment: What's with the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you question correctly, then you just need to create a new list for B values and add them to the list.

So after getting the result set from executing the query...

```
List<Object> aValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> bValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
while ( results.hasNext() ) {
    aValues.add( results.next().get( "A" ));
    bValues.add( results.next().get( "B" ));
}
```

I do not know what your trying to achieve, but FYI the query will already return a List where each object is a list .

Comment: Yes I got it right. I was messing with list names, and kept getting results from one variable only to both my lists. Thank you anyway